# Push notifications issues: key,failed/message not reach

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, apple-push-notifications, app42

I'm still new to iOS dev.
And I'm very, very new to whole APNS idea. I followed many tutorials, and didn't go so well.
I'd like to ask some questions.

1. Can I use same `.certSigningRequest` file for dev/dist/apns certificates? Does it matter if some of this certificates from this `.certSigningRequest` have been revoked?
2. When I export my key in keychain to `.p12` file, can I use this one for both dev/distribute version?
3. If my server open port 2195, by giving `.pem` generated from above cer, my server should be able to send push message, right?
4. How can I unsubscribe/unregister from my device and/or from server/apns service? I mean when I need to remove, and try to build&run the code again.
   4.1 How does
   `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] unregisterForRemoteNotifications];`
   really work? Does it tell apns not to send message/just turn it off? How can my server/provider know if device need to unsubscribe?

I find this tutorial really useful:  http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1
And here some questions I have about what I encountered.
1. The sample app from the tutorial worked fine, using both my laptop & my server to send a message. But after a few days, it doesn't. (the response is still 'Connected to APNS Message successfully delivered', but the message never reach my device)
 What could be the cause? My friend have revoked a dev cert? (I shared acc. w/ my friends) Or I reinstall the app? I also tried method `unregisterForRemoteNotifications` & register again, but nothing happens.
2. I also tried https://apphq.shephertz.com for a provider. This one requires `.p12` key file in their format. ([link](http://blogs.shephertz.com/2013/07/03/configure-send-push-notification-on-ios-device/)) I have another project (this one is unity) register apns thru the app. It seems fine since I can see device token & user store in the web. But when I tried to send message, I got an error, like
`iOS KeystoreException Device ID : <my-device-token> : Invalid keystore password! Verify settings for connecting to Apple...` Does anyone know what this mean?

Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Please make sure that your p12 file password is correct that you have used to store it on App42 server through management console.

Comment: @ajay I did upload & it said 'IOS Key Submitted successfully.' But I didn't know if it work, or where I can see a list of my key details.

Comment: You have to remember your password by your own. There is no way you can find it from somewhere. Alternatively, recreate a new p12 file with new password and upload it again.